# Why can't I use condition for columns in dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

```
np.random.seed(101)
array = np.random.randint(10, 50, (10,5))
df = pd.DataFrame(data = array, index = "A B C D E F G H I J".split(), columns = "VAL1 VAL2 VAL3 VAL4 VAL5".split())
```

This is working ↓↓

```
df.loc[df["VAL2"] > 25,"VAL2":"VAL4"]
```

Why isn't this  ↓↓

```
`df.loc["A":"C", df["C"] < 30]`
```

Comment: Include the error you are receiving and what it is you are trying to do. Also, just this `df["C"] < 30` would give you a KeyError since your `df` do not have any column named `"C"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df["C"]` raises a KeyError since is tries to look it up in the columns.

Try:

```py
df.loc["A":"C", df.loc["C"]< 30]
```